# Scheduling a Gradle task between DEX generation and a native build

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a Gradle task that depends on the generation of `classes.dex`, as produced by the 'mergeDexRelease' task. How should I configure the dependencies so that when I run 'assembleRelease' and the like, this task gets run in the right order? i.e.: `mergeDexRelease > myTask > ... > assembleRelease`.

This is what I have currently but it's not working:

```
android {
    /* ... */

    task myTask(type: Exec) {
        dependsOn 'mergeDexRelease'
        commandLine ["..."]
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        externalNativeBuildRelease.dependsOn 'myTask'
    }
}
```